# iPhone communication using Sockets

Tags: iphone, ios, json, sockets

I'm trying to to use an application to communicate with Windows via sockets.  At the minimum, I'm trying to at least figure out how I can create a connection from the iPhone (maybe using the iPhone to ping the Windows machine?)  I'm not really clear on where I need to start.  I'm pretty new to iOS development in general, and brand new to socket/network programming.  I've tried several tutorials that haven't gotten me far.  My goal is:

- Connect to a server via sockets (the server will be a Windows machine with a service waiting for incoming connections from the iPhone)
- I will eventually be sending JSON packets to the server, as well as receiving JSON packets from the server
- Come up with a response in the iPhone indicating success or failure

If possible, I would like to write/build the client piece first, but I have been lost thus far.  Hopefully the nice folks in the SO community can lend a hand and point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The server is a Windows machine.  I'm trying to connect to a service (Windows Executable) which will send/receive JSON packets.

Comment: Is it possible for you, to get the server side work by HTTP? This will make your implementation easier as the client side part is well documented and tutorialized for this. Can you get the JSON response on a third machine's browser by accessing http://<ip of json windows machine>/pathToJsonGeneratingScript ? Or do you have protocol documentation, in case it is not HTTP? It is useful to set up the server side first and have it confirmed working (e.g. by network access via browser). Otherwise you may get into fog quickly with unsure server and client side implementations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is very wide especially that it does not target a specific programing problem. I will give you some guidelines or point of start.

For iPhone you need to learn how to work with `NSStream` and you might start from here: [Stream Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Streams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000188i). You will need an output stream and an input stream so you can manage outgoing and incoming communications easily and in parallel. In other words you will benefit from the `NSInputStream` and the `NSOutputStream` classes which are derived from the main `NSStream` class. When you will send data using streams you will send raw data using `uint8_t` buffers so it is not obligatory to use JSON packets; I personally don't, but it is up to you.

On Windows I assume you will be using C# so you will need to learn `TcpListener` which listens on a certain IP address and a port number that you specify. This can start you up a bit: [TcpListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Also you will need `TcpClient` through which you will read and write to the stream.

For efficient server you need to work Asynchronously and `TcpClient` has synchronous and asynchronous methods for that. Also for better functionality you might need to use threading in your server, or use the built in `BackgroundWorker` class which makes things much more easy.

I don't suggest programming the client alone then the server, I believe that they should go in parallel because it is a 2 sided communication and if you try that you will see that you must work little here and little there. It is not a surprise if I tell you that when I work on my client/server app I have on my desk a Mac and a PC and I switch between them every while.

Finally, I would like to comment on something which you did not ask about. Since your client is a mobile device then you have to expect that it is not always on (or no Internet connection always on it), therefore prepare yourself to have some database work in the server to be able to store messages that need to be sent later...

I hope this can help you start up. If you have a more specific question I might be able to illustrate better. By the way, this job is not that easy but it is great fun if you really like programming, especially when you start to get your first results ;)

Comment: This was really helpful for me.  I will begin by familiarizing myself with Stream Programming.  Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You are welcome, after you start you will have more specific questions and then help will be more accurate :) Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must use sockets, do yourself a favour and grab a nice socket library like AsyncSocket. https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket

But better still try doing it over http first and only move to sockets when you really must do so.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is using some kind of custom protocol, you can use BSD socket API. If the server is speaking HTTP protocol, then use either:

1. NSURLConnection - for asynchronous communication from the main thread.
2. Load synchronously using NSData but from a separate thread.

Example for #2:

```
NSString *url = @"http://example.com";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] 
    initWithBytes: [data bytes]
    length:[data length] 
    encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTP, as already stated, life will be much easier. No use in reinventing the wheel when you already have a protocol as extensive and as widely used as HTTP.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is a nice library for communicating to a web server and comes built-in with the ability to encode/decode JSON.

Example using AFNetworking to communicate using HTTP, JSON, and REST API.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *jsonRequest = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                                             path:@"user/login" 
                                                       parameters:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:user, @"username", password, @"password", nil]];
    //Make operation from request
    AFJSONRequestOperation *jsonOperation = 
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:jsonRequest
                                                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
                                                        //Block will be called when request is successful
                                                    } 
                                                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
                                                        //Block will be called if request has failed
                                                    }];
    //Start request
    [httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:jsonOperation];
```

Pretty easy to use, I think it is easier than NSURLConnection. The use of blocks makes it a lot more initiative. Plus, you will not have to worry about JSON encoding/decoding. The JSON will be encoded/decoded for you directly from an objective-c object to JSON (or from JSON to objective-c object).