# Some time apple push notification not getting

Tags: objective-c, ios8, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iOS  application in iOS 8 .That has one module called message sending. This module developed with help of Apple push notification. My issue is some time we are not getting Push message to iOS  device .The server successfully sent the message to APNS. Is it any  APNS reliability issue?

i am using the following steps:

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
            if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)])
                {
                    UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                }
 return YES;
    }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings
            {
               [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
            }

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
        {

        }

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
        {

        }

 - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- APNs are not reliable, they are not 100% guaranteed to reach the client.
- As of Apple's documentation, APNs are *best effort*, so many times they might not reach.

Via  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968501/can-server-to-client-messaging-rely-on-apns)

Answer (score 0):

Samraan is not wrong, Apple does not guarantee delivery, however it is pretty reliable in my experience. What I do notice from the code you have posted here is that you have an empty implementation for `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. When your app is active, and it receives a push notification, there is no system banner or alert shown. Instead the notification is delivered to the `didReceiveRemoteNotification` callback for your app to handle directly. If you have an empty definition of this function and you send a notification to that device, it may appear like the notification never arrived, but instead it was just hidden.

You could try adding a UIAlertView popup to this callback to find out if this is what is happening in your case.